# Scroll panel programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to learn more About C#.

I just have a big problem with scrolling a panel.

I have a panel contains many buttons in Windows form,
trying to scroll it with Two Button Scroll up and scroll down.

I search in google I found many codes like this one :

```
CategoryFlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition = 
    new Point(0, CategoryFlowPanel.VerticalScroll.Value +
                 CategoryFlowPanel.VerticalScroll.SmallChange * 7);
```

I mean something like-

```
CategoryFlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 50);
```

also I found this :

```
using (Control c = new Control() { Parent=p, Height = 1, Top = p.ClientSize.Height + pos })
{
    p.ScrollControlIntoView(c);
}
```

and many other but they are working  ONLY IF autoscroll is true

and when autoscroll is true the scroll bars will be visible

so my question is -

**Is there code can work without autoscroll?**

or is there way to hide the scroll bars when autoscroll is true ?

I'm trying to do

```
Panel.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
```

but its not working.

Sorry for my bad English, and Thanks in advance.

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? WPF? ...?

Comment: @UweKeim WinForms. sorry for not mention that

Comment: @TaW umm, how about using vScrollBar, i mean  i transfer value from the panel scrollbar to vScrollBar1 , then hide the panel scroll bar , so i can scroll the panel using vScrollBar1.  i'm not really sure if this possible xD

Comment: @TaW  i just have alot of button sort in vertical , and  i want to put arrow up and arrow down ( buttons) to scroll them, do you have an idea that can help instead of using a panel ? sry for my bad English again, and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll WinForms panel without scrollbars being visible by setting `HorizontalScroll.Value` and `VerticalScroll.Value` programmatically. This approach works with `AutoScroll = false` as you need.

Comment: You can't do this, as max value of scrollbar depends on how big is virtual ("scrollable") space of your panel. You need to make sure your content doesn't stretch too far.